# How to query data from latest partition in interval partitioned table

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

I have an interval partitioned table: PARTITION_TEST.
I need to pick a data from the last partition. Is it possible, without refering to dba_tab_partition table?

This table will have only 5 partitions at a time. Is there any way to select data from 5th partition position ?

Something like,

```
SELECT * FROM PARTITION_TEST partition_position(5)?
```

Comment: please include the table structure as well.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT <column_name_list>
FROM <table_name> PARTITION (<partition_name>)`;

Comment: Do you know anything about the data in the last partition; will it always include the current date, for example, or some other known value in the partition key column?

Comment: Yes it's possible. `Select * from parttion_test partition for (trunc(sysdate))`. I don't remember exactly how it's goes but it's something similar for my example. Google it

Comment: Only if you know the last (fifth, in this case) partition will include a particular value; sysdate was just an example. But yes, I was thinking of the `for` syntax, and trying to establish if it might work here. You can't actually use sysdate though (ORA-14108, seems to be treated as a bind in this context), or a partition number.

Comment: select * from mytable partition for (to_date('20150801', 'YYYYMMDD'))   This would get data for the latest partition assuming its partitioned by date per month, and the current month is Aug of 2015.